# Unable to show progressDialog on UI thread while downloading images from server all at a time

Tags: android, multithreading

```
   private void initLabReportsAdapter(Cursor cursor) {


    LabListHolder mHolder;


    if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        // //Log(TAG, "no LabRecords available");
        noLabReports.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        return;
    }
    noLabReports.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {

        cursor.moveToPosition(i);
        View v = contentLayout.getChildAt(i);
        if (v == null) {

            v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_labreports, null);
            mHolder = new LabListHolder();
            mHolder.attachment = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id_lab.iv_attachment_thumbnail);
            mHolder.uploadedBy = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id_lab.tv_uploadby);
            mHolder.reportDate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id_lab.tv_date);
            mHolder.type = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id_lab.tv_category);
            mHolder.typeDescription = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id_lab.tv_description);

            v.setTag(mHolder);
            contentLayout.addView(v);

        } else {
            mHolder = (LabListHolder) v.getTag();
        }
        int uniqueid = cursor.getColumnIndex(DbManager.COL_LAB_RECORD_UNIQUEID);

        String Uniqueid = cursor.getString(uniqueid);


        try {

            int category = cursor.getColumnIndex(DbManager.COL_LAB_RECORD_CATEGORY);
            int Category = cursor.getInt(category) - 1;
            String CATEGORY = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.labcategory)[Category];
            mHolder.type.setText(CATEGORY);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            mHolder.type.setText("Others");
        }

        // Set uploaded By
        int by = cursor.getColumnIndex(DbManager.COL_LAB_RECORD_UPLOADEDBY);
        String By = cursor.getString(by);
        String Patientid = DbManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getPatientId();
        if (Patientid.equalsIgnoreCase(By))
        {
            // mHolder.uploadby.setImageResource(R.drawable.by_me);
            mHolder.uploadedBy.setText("By Me");
        }
        else
        {
            // mHolder.uploadby.setImageResource(R.drawable.by_hospital);
            mHolder.uploadedBy.setText("By Hospital");
        }

        // Set Description
        int description = cursor.getColumnIndex(DbManager.COL_LAB_RECORD_DESCRIPTION);
        String Description = cursor.getString(description);
        mHolder.typeDescription.setText(Html.fromHtml(Description));

        // Set Report Date
        int indexModified = cursor.getColumnIndex(DbManager.COL_LAB_RECORD_DATE);
        String strModified = cursor.getString(indexModified);
        String Today = null;

        if (strModified != null)
        {
            try {

                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
                        Locale.getDefault());
                String formattedDOB = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy ", Locale.getDefault())
                        .format(sdf.parse(strModified));
                mHolder.reportDate.setText(formattedDOB);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                mHolder.reportDate.setText(strModified);
            }
        }

        // Set Image
        int attachfile = cursor.getColumnIndex(DbManager.COL_LAB_RECORD_FILE);
        String AttachFile = cursor.getString(attachfile);
        AttachFile = AttachFile.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
        final String DownloadFile = getString(R.string.api_labrecord) + AttachFile;

        if (DownloadFile.contains("_"))
        {
            Labfilename = DownloadFile.split("_");
        }
        else
        {
            Labfilename = DownloadFile.split("/");
        }

        final String SaveFileAs = Uniqueid + Labfilename[Labfilename.length - 1];

        try
        {
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + getResources().getString(R.string.check_lab_reports_exists), SaveFileAs);

            Log.i(TAG, "File name:" + file.getName());
            if (file.exists()) {
                // Do action
                Log.i(TAG, "Already Downloaded");
                if (Util.checkImageExtension(SaveFileAs))
                {
                    Log.i(TAG, " checkImageExtension true");

                    imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                            + getResources().getString(R.string.check_lab_reports_slash)
                            + SaveFileAs;
                    Log.i(TAG, "imagePath:" + imagePath);

                    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);



                  mHolder.attachment.setImageBitmap(bmp.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 64, 64,
                    true));



                }
                else if (SaveFileAs.endsWith(".pdf") || SaveFileAs.endsWith(".PDF"))
                {
                    String PdfPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                            + getResources().getString(R.string.check_lab_reports_slash)
                            + SaveFileAs;

                    mHolder.attachment.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                            R.drawable.file_pdf_icon));

                } else if (SaveFileAs.endsWith(".doc") || SaveFileAs.endsWith(".DOC")
                        || SaveFileAs.endsWith(".docx") || SaveFileAs.endsWith(".DOCX"))
                {
                    String PdfPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                            + getResources().getString(R.string.check_lab_reports_slash)
                            + SaveFileAs;

                    mHolder.attachment.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                            R.drawable.file_doc_icon));

                }
                else
                {
                    Log.i(TAG, " checkImageExtension false");

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            getResources().getString(R.string.file_exists_in_folder),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
            else
            {
                Log.i(TAG, " file not downloaded");

                if (!Util.isNetworkOnline(getApplicationContext())) {
                    return;
                }
                double externalMemory = (getAvailableExternalMemory() * 1024);
                int value_external = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(externalMemory).substring(
                        0, 1));
                if (externalMemory != 0.0)
                {
                    if (value_external >= 1)
                    {


                        new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(DownloadFile, "LabReports",
                                SaveFileAs).get();


                        imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                                + getResources().getString(R.string.check_lab_reports_slash)
                                + SaveFileAs;
                        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);

                        System.out.println("Download thread_________20="
                                + System.currentTimeMillis());
                        mHolder.attachment.setImageBitmap(bmp.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 64, 64,
                                true));


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                "There is no enough space in sdcard, please remove some content",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please insert memory card to download files.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Log.e("Error", "Downloading File");
            if (mProgressDialog != null) {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                mProgressDialog = null;
            }
        }

        mHolder.attachment.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (SaveFileAs.endsWith(".pdf") || SaveFileAs.endsWith(".PDF")) {
                    if (Util.canDisplayPdf(getApplicationContext()))
                    {
                        PDFdisplay(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                                + getResources().getString(R.string.check_lab_reports_slash)
                                + SaveFileAs, LabReportsActivity.this);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Pleast install the PDF reader", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                } else {

                    imgShow(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                            + getResources().getString(R.string.check_lab_reports_slash)
                            + SaveFileAs, LabReportsActivity.this);
                }
            }
        });
    }



}
```

I'm calling initLabReportsAdapter(cursor) on UI thread and I want show the progress dialogue while converting Imagefile path into bitmap,
 when I try to show dialogue before calling this method dialogue becomes visible once last line of for-loop ends and becomes invisible .

I want to show while downloading Images from API call 
Can someone please help me

Comment: only post relevant code. I (and most others) won't read that much...
That being said, to download something and report back to the UI thread, use an AsyncTask.

Comment: please use asynctask bro.  u can call progress dialog in pre execute and dismiss in postexecute

Comment: Thanks for the comments guy's.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much guy's, I haven't used any ImageLoader library to convert filepath into image(thumbnail)

Now I have replaced the

```
 imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                            + getResources().getString(R.string.check_lab_reports_slash)
                            + SaveFileAs;
                    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);


                    mHolder.attachment.setImageBitmap(bmp.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 64, 64,
                            true));
```

**By**

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(file)
                                    .into(mHolder.attachment);
```

**The actual problem was converting imagepath into bitmap and setting that bitmap to an imageview** was taking hell lot of time so, I just replaced conversion work by  [Picasso library](https://github.com/square/picasso), It avoided loading time